# Spin Control in Delphi

Tags: delphi, controls

I want to use a "spin button control" (also known as an up-down control) in my Delphi Win 32 application (I'm using Delphi 2007).

The aim is to have a control that looks like in Microsoft Office:

[image of up/down control in Powerpoint. http://img167.imageshack.us/my.php?image=updownzn8.png](http://img167.imageshack.us/my.php?image=updownzn8.png)

I found this on the Microsoft website: [CSpinButtonCtrl Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/sfac27cz(VS.80).aspx)

But I haven't so far found a control that uses this class - here's where I've been searching:

- The SpinEdit control in Delphi looks well... not so good, and doesn't seem to use the official Microsoft control
- The JVCL classes have their own implementation
- A Google search did not return any results (except some home-brew up/down controls)
- I couldn't find something in the Jedi API as well

Can somebody please point me to where I can find a Delphi implementation of the common spin control from Microsoft, or how I can do that myself?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have a look at TUpDown. It wraps the Win32 control.

Answer (score 2):

Raize Components [Raize.com](http://www.raize.com) have a nice one

Answer (score 0):

[TMS Software](http://tmssoftware.com) do a wide range of components including spin edits (fancy an iPhone style one!) and I have found their support through the newsgroups to be excellent.